# How do I aggregate data from many files into one file?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have this directory structure for about 100 users.

```
users
- user1
  - info.txt
- user2
  - info.txt
- user3
  - info.txt
...
```

Inside the `info.txt` files, the contents look like this.

```
5 some_other_info
```

Basically, it's just one line, containing a number, a space, then some text (may have spaces within).

I'd like to create a file `result.txt` that looks like this.

```
user1 5
user2 6
user3 7
...
```

Where `user1`, `user2`, `user3`, ... matches the directory name and the numbers match what's in their respective `info.txt` files.

You can assume that the user directories have no spaces in their names.

What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk '{split(FILENAME,u,"/"); print u[2], $1}' users/*/info.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with a simple `for` loop.

```
{
  for userd in users/*/; do 
    if [[ -e "$userd/info.txt" ]]; then
      read num _ < "$userd/info.txt"
      printf '%s %s\n' "$user" "$num"
    fi
  done
} > out.txt
```

Comment: There's no need to wrap this in curly braces.

Answer (score 3):

A variation on Stephane's answer:

```
$ cd users && \
      find -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name info.txt  \
    | xargs awk '{ split(FILENAME,u,"/"); print u[2], $1 }'
```

The use of (GNU) `find` and `xargs` protects against the number of users exceeding the maximal number of program arguments (which is system dependent).

(xargs will correctly split the input and repeatedly call awk if necessary)

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in users/*/info.txt; do
    set -- $(< $f)
    num=$1

    # choose one of:
    user=$(basename $(dirname $f))
    # or
    dir=${f%/*}; user=${dir##*/}

    echo $user $num
done
```

Comment: Using set to split the string is interesting. I like that approach.

Comment: @jordanm This has undesirable consequences in certain rare circumstances. For example, if `some_other_info` is `/auto/someserver/*`, this could trigger some automounting.